# Replace a column value with random values

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

I want to replace values in a column with randomized values

```
NO  LINE
--  ----
1   1
1   2
1   3
1   4
2   1
2   2
3   1
4   1
4   2
```

I want to randomize column NO and replace with random values. I have 5 million records and doing something like below script gives me 5 million unique NO's but as you can see NO is not unique and i want the same random value assigned for the same NO.

```
UPDATE table1
SET    NO= abs(checksum(NewId())) % 100000000
```

I want my resultant dataset like below

```
NO     LINE
------ ----
99     1
99     2
99     3
99     4
1092   1
1092   2
3456   1
41098  1
41098  2
```

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend `rand()` with a seed:

```
UPDATE table1
    SET NO = FLOOR(rand(NO) * 100000000);
```

This runs a slight risk of collisions, so two different `NO` rows could get the same value.

If the numbers do not need to be "random" you can give them consecutive values in an arbitrary order and avoid collisions:

```
with toupdate as (
      select t1.*,
             dense_rank() over (order by rand(NO), no) as new_no
      from t
     )
update toupdate
    set no = new_no;
```

Comment: This is what i did but get an error "The multi-part identifier "toupdate.New_Claim_no" could not be bound." with CTE_toupdate as (
      select Claim_no,
             dense_rank() over (order by rand(Claim_no), Claim_no) as New_Claim_no
      from HospiceFinal  --order by claim_no
UPDATE HospiceFinal
    set Claim_no = toupdate.New_Claim_no
From CTE_toupdate t1
inner join HospiceFinal t2
on t1.claim_no = t2.claim_no